# Trigger custom JSP tag manually

Tags: ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee

Lets pretend that we have custom JSP tag somewhere on page:

```
<myTag:loadList data=${asyncData} />
```

When a page starts loading, **asynchronous** AJAX call to server is made. As a result of this call the data for  *asyncData* parameter should be provided.

The question is - how can I "trigger" my custom tag for rendering manually based on successful AJAX request? Thank you!

Comment: AJAX occurs client-side. JSP occurs server-side. So, once the response is sent it is too late to evaluate your custom tag.  Why do you need AJAX? Why can't the server compute everything before it sends response?

Comment: The point is that this page has heavy-weight list of data. We need to show page first of all and then compute data by means of AJAX and show the list ultimately

Comment: You could have two JSPs. The first one to send the HTML of the page. That page could have the code that makes the AJAX call to the second page. The second page contains your custom tag. The AJAX call could be triggered by the onload event of the first page.

Comment: rickz, do you mean I should include the second page into the first?

Comment: No. AJAX calls the second page.

Comment: But, in that case, what must be the response from that AJAX call to the second page and what should I do with that?

Comment: The response should be the data. You can use JavaScript to add the data to the page.